# iPhone upload image speed advice

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

I have an app that allows you to take a picture, adjust the jpeg quality size (10-100%) and then send it to a server using ASIFormDataRequest (part of the ASIHTTPRequest implementation). This works fine over a network connection, but over the celluar network it appears to sit there for 5-10 minutes attempting to transmit the image post data, before failing (even with the quality at 10%).

On comparing this to the image uploads that the Twitter and Facebook apps provide (which take ~30 seconds to a minute) this isn't exactly ideal. I wondered if anyone could give me any advice about either how to speed up my data transfer, or monitor it so I can see exactly where the problem lies.

Once I get back to my mac laptop tonight I'll post a code snippet of exactly what it is I'm doing, in case that helps.

EDIT: Heres the code snippet:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"...upload.php"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSTimeInterval time = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", time];
...
float compressionRate = [userAccountView getCompressionRate];
NSLog(@"Compression rate: %.1f", compressionRate);
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageForView, compressionRate);
[request setData:imageData withFileName:fileName andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"userfile"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

The .. code comment is where I just stick an 'uploading' image over the view. I suppose I could make the call synchronous as opposed to asynchronous, do you think that may improve performance? I have left it that way in case at a later stage I wanted to allow the user to do other bits while it is uploading.

Any advice would be great :)

Thanks,

Dan

EDIT:

Jesse, thanks for the comment - I added in [request setUploadProcessDelegate:self] and put in the required method to monitor the data that was being sent, and it all seemed to be sending okay.

JosephH - I have added in "[ASIHTTPRequest setShouldThrottleBandwidthForWWAN:YES]" as suggested, and have also added "set_time_limit(0);" into the PHP upload script (in case of timeouts) and now the data does seem to be sending and being retrieved over the cellular network, so horray! Am playing around now with file compressions etc. to find the best one for the best quality. ATM it seems like 0.3 is pretty good quality, and transfers in roughly 30 seconds or so, which is what I was looking for!

I was also incorrectly setting the compression rate, as I was using 10-100 as opposed to 0.0-1.0, so I have also corrected that.

Thanks for your quick help guys in solving my issue!!

Comment: i would start by figuring out if it is actually connecting over the cellular network by NSLog in the delegate methods you implement for ASIHTTPRequest (don't recall the exact names right this second)

I think i remember there being a setting in ASIHTTPRequest that either disallows or severely limits the data transfer over cellular network. if so, i know you can change it to allow it.

Comment: Hey Jesse, thanks for the input - have edited my question for what you have suggested. Is the "setShouldThrottleBandwidthForWWAN:YES" setting suggested to me by JosephH what you were thinking of with regards to the data transfer stuff?

Comment: Glad to hear you've got it working. I guess the compression ratio was probably the most important fix - I guess it was generating pretty huge files before you fixed that!

Comment: Well I believe from the setup that because it goes from 0-1, and I was putting in 10-100, it would always send the highest quality picture (which is about 2meg). Its thanks to you I noticed it because until you stated it, it hadn't crossed my mind, so thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first thing to do is to check what size the data you're sending is:

```
 NSLog(@"imageData size = %d", [imageData length]);
```

Does your NSLog correctly show the compressionRate is set to 0.1 for 10%?

ASIHTTPRequest also has a lot of debug logging you can enable - see ASIHTTPRequestConfig.h; just change everything from 0 to 1. It may not reveal anything of interest, but it is certainly worth looking at.

Are you calling `[ASIHTTPRequest setShouldThrottleBandwidthForWWAN:YES]` ?

When it fails, how does it fail, what is the error, what does any logging on the server show?

(If you find out anything extra, please do edit it into the question and post a comment and I'll take another look)

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks for the answer - have commented in the question as requested, however quick side question I forgot to ask (may sound dumb) but what does "setShouldThrottleBandwidthForWWAN:YES" actually do? And should I leave it on all the time, or switch it off when using a WiFi connection for example?

Comment: The bandwidth throttling is actual an experimental feature - it's documented here:
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#throttling_bandwidth

I wasn't particularly suggesting you should use it, but it could have been important to know if you were already trying to use it or not. If you do decide to use it, you don't need to switch it off on wifi - ASIHTTPRequest handles that side of things automatically.